# How do I verify installation requirements in Maximo 7.5 install?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, maximo

I am trying to install an [Admin Workstation with a demo database for Maximo 7.5](http://web.archive.org/web/20150403211647/http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21498420) on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I downloaded two files, 1) MAM_LAUNCHPAD_7.5_EIMG_1_OF_2_REF.zip and 2) MAM_LAUNCHPAD_7.5_EIMG_2_OF_2_REF.zip .

[image]

I extracted the contents into the same folder and ran launchpad64 as Administrator.

When I click on Verify installation requirements, I get an error in the command prompt box that says:

> CTGIN8125E : Administrative priviliges are required to execute this script. 
>   Please any key to continue . . .

I believe it has to do with running cscript.exe that is normally in c:
\windows\system32

My security role is Domain User, but was able to add myself in the Administrators role. I would think with Administrators role, I would have full privileges.

[image]

I have the [video of some the steps I performed here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94MFDD3gaFE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a local user on the server
- Give that local user Administrator role
- Log locally into the server as that local user: server\local_user
- right click on launchpad64 as run as Administrator

You should be able to Verify installation requirements now.